# How can I recreate canned whipped cream from scratch?

Tags: restaurant-mimicry, whipped-cream

I tried by using two quarts of heavy cream, two cups of sugar and a spoon of honey and mixed it all together but I feel like it's missing something to the flavor.

I'm trying to create something similar to what you get out of a can of whipped cream. Reddi-whip to be exact.

These are the ingredients: Nonfat milk, cream, sugar, corn syrup, maltodextrin, inulin (chicory extract), cellulose, mono- and diglycerides polysorbate 80, artificial flavors, carrageenan.

Can someone explain what these are: (maltodextrin, inulin (chicory extract), cellulose, mono- and diglycerides polysorbate 80, artificial flavors, carrageenan)

Answer (score 6):

Sigh, I was trying to avoid answering this, but feel compelled to provide some information after all your revisions.  I'm answering only this part of the question:

> Can someone explain what these are: (maltodextrin, inulin (chicory
>   extract), cellulose, mono- and diglycerides polysorbate 80, artificial
>   flavors, carrageenan)

Let's break that down:

- maltodextrin is a sweetener
- inulin is also a sweetener
- cellulose is a fiber (wood, basically) used as a stabilizer
- mono- and diglycerides are emulsifiers, that make the cream smoother
- polysorbate 80 another emulsifier
- carrageenan algae, also a stabilizer

Now, "artificial flavors" could literally mean anything, which is a big challenge for your recreation experiment.  Not only does it not say which flavors they've added, the formula may be a trade secret.

Comment: I believe the artificial flavor is mostly imitation vanilla, so I'd definitely add that.  No idea what the rest of the flavoring is.

Answer (score 4):

If your trying to imitate the flavor of 'reddi-whip' then you're going to have to play around with the chemistry to get at what you want. If you are wanting to make home-made whip cream come spraying out of a canister, then I have just the thing for you: An NO2 whip cream canister can be purchased at any of several outlets.
[image]
[NO2 Whip Cream Canister](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01DZ2HZ2U)
Just add whip cream, sugar and give it a good shake then connect an [NO2 cartridge](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01IPBEPTM) (or [CO2, cheaper and more readily available](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00304SLAO) but be careful to get food grade, your average 'paint ball' CO2 cartridge can have unpleasant additives)  and you have 'ready whip' (you can also add a variety of other flavorings, I enjoy Amaretto... ) Be careful, a little bit of sugar and some flavored syrup can go a long way in here.

Comment: Thanks, I said CO2, but NO2 is probably a better option for food items.

Comment: The choice of CO2 or NO2 depends on the food.  NO2 is highly soluble in fat, making it ideal for whipped cream.  CO2 dissolves readily in water, which is why it's used in carbonated drinks.  Also note that CO2 makes water acidic, which is another reason you wouldn't use for whipped cream.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the label gives you a long list of stabilizers, sweeteners, emulsifiers, and "artificial flavors", none of which are likely to significantly alter the flavor profile of your homemade replica.

If you are needing to bump the flavor, a (small!) pinch of salt helps accentuate flavor without making things salty. Vanilla extract could help -- however, at that point you're starting to move beyond just whipped cream flavor.

**Your biggest challenge is going to be *consistency***, regardless of the flavor profile you accomplish. Texture, or mouthfeel, can be a big influence on whether something "tastes right," and homemade whipped cream is definitely thicker than its canned counterpart. To replicate texture of Reddi-Whip or similar brands, you need a whipped cream canister that aerates the cream-sugar mixture, and [Cos Callis answered that thoroughly](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/90625/17272).

Comment: I agree too, tried vanilla last time and he liked it but his answer was not very promising. I just do not understand how can I replicate something that is factory made, without having that recipe

Comment: Honestly, the hardest thing to replicate about canned whipped cream is the texture. My homemade whipped cream tends to be much thicker (something I like, but not "authentic").

Comment: Mine comes out the same way, except not super white like the one in the cans, but thats because of the heavy cream

Comment: I would take exception to the notion that canned whipped cream is authentic.  Authentic whipped cream is just that, whipped cream.  The canned stuff is an imitation aerated convenience.  That said, some prefer that, and that is fine.  The only way I can think you are really likely to come close though is a CO2 type pressure aerator.

Comment: I did have "authentic" in quotes, hahaha ;)

Comment: ;)  I know.  And I am one of those that canned whip cream, the only use I have for it is for "chipmunck cheeks", while my family looks at fresh whipped cream as if it is left over roadkill.  I think I am adopted.

Comment: The texture has to be recreated with a gas syphon, shown in the other answer. As for the flavor, that's much harder, it could be anything.

Comment: It is highly likely that because of the major ingredients in Reddi-Wip (real cream for one), that Conagra is using a homoginizer in their process. A homoginizer and the needed support equipment and installation is not cheap or something to practically do at home.

Comment: @Cynetta True -- but OP can probably get away with it since he won't need to make the whipped cream shelf stable, just taste/feel similar.